# Wanted: example of a non-algebraic singularity

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory, examples

Given a finitely generated $\def\CC{\mathbb C}\CC$-algebra $R$ and a $\CC$-point (maximal ideal) $p\in Spec(R)$, I define the *singularity type* of $p\in Spec(R)$ to be the isomorphism class of the completed local ring $\hat R_p$, as a $\CC$-algebra.

Do there exist non-algebraic singularity types? That is, does there exist a complete local ring with residue field $\CC$ which is formally finitely generated (i.e. has a surjection from some $\CC[[x_1,\dots, x_n]]$), but is not the complete local ring of a finitely generated $\CC$-algebra at a maximal ideal?

Googling for "non-algebraic singularity" suggests that the answer is yes, but I can't find a specific example. I would expect that it should be possible to write down a power series in two variables $f(x,y)$ so that $\CC[[x,y]]/f(x,y)$ is non-algebraic.

> What is a specific formally finitely generated non-algebraic singularity?

Comment: One idea I had is to take a non-algebraic variety $X$, and consider the completed local ring at the cone point of a cone on $X$. The problem is that making a cone on $X$ involves choosing a very ample line bundle on $X$. But as soon as $X$ is projective, it is algebraic by GAGA.

Comment: Regarding your expectation, any analytic plane curve singularity is in fact algebraic. See, for example, Corollary 7.7.3 of the book by Casas-Alvero "Singularities of plane curves", London Mathematical Society Lecture Note Series, 276. I'm not sure though whether a similar result holds for formal planar singularities but it seems possible to me.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but maybe you find something relevant in Angelos answer here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/51530/analytic-vs-formal-vs-etale-singularities 

Comment: Do you want the singularity type to include the datum of the topology on the completed local ring?

Comment: @S. Carnahan: that information is automatically included, since the topology is induced by the maximal ideal.

Comment: If the singularity is isolated (that is if $\mathbb{ℂ}[[x,y]]/f(x,y)$ minus its closed point is formally smooth over $\mathbb{C}$), then it is algebraic. This is Theorem 3.8 in Artin's paper on "Algebraic approximation of structures over Henselian local rings", at IHES, hence easily available on numdam.org. It uses Artin's approximation theorem plus works of Hironaka

Comment: @Joël: That's very interesting; thank you for the reference! (http://archive.numdam.org/article/PMIHES_1969__36__23_0.pdf) The result is over an arbitrary field, too. I'd like to say that this means that the singularity at the generic point of the singular locus must be algebraic, but of course localization does not commute with completion.

Comment: @Anton: I like your question, and I am surprised it has not been fully answered yet. There must be no active singularity theorists
on math overflow at this moment. So for what has been written so far in comment, it seems that there will be no example of a non-algebraic
formal singularity of the form $\mathbb{C}[[x,y]]/(f(X,Y))$ but I can't prove it (I am really a great beginner in that theory, I should say). I have two ideas about how one could prove it:
One way would be to use Theorem 3.8 of Artin quoted in my comment, 
and to prove that a singularity of this form is necessarily isolated...

Comment: but I have not been able to do it. An other way would be to prove
that a formal singularity of this type is at least analytic,
and then to apply the theorem quoted in Ulrich's comment. I
thought that it was a consequence of Artin's approximation theorem that any formal singularity was analytic, but I wasn't able to 
get sure that it was true and I have to go for dinner. I am very curious though.


Answer (score 35, accepted):

I got this example from Frank Loray. I'll explain the analytic version, but the formal variant works just as well.

Let $U\subset \mathbb{C}$ be open. Choose two holomorphic functions $f$, $g$ which are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{C}$ (e.g. $f(z)=z$, $g(z)=e^z$). For simplicity, assume that $f$, $g$, $0$, $1$ never coincide (pairwise) on $U$. Now define $X\subset U\times\mathbb{C}^2$ (with coordinates $z$, $x$, $y$) as the union of $x=0$, $y=0$, $x=y$, $y=f(z)\,x$, and $y=g(z)\,x$. Thus, if we freeze $z$, we get five lines in the plane, with slopes $\infty$, $0$, $1$, $f(z)$ and $g(z)$. Globally, $X$ is the union of five copies of $U\times\mathbb{C}$ meeting along $Z:=U\times\mathbb{0}$.

Now, the point is that the cross-ratio of four (ordered) lines through the origin in the plane is an intrinsically defined invariant. In particular, independently of the coordinates, we can recover $f$ and $g$ as holomorphic functions on the singular locus $Z$. If $X$ were isomorphic to a complex open subset of an algebraic variety, $f$ and $g$ would have to be algebraically dependent because $\dim Z=1$: contradiction.

Comment: Beautiful! ${}$

Comment: Ok, I buy it. I was confused for a bit because I thought you needed to include the information of how to fix $z$ in order to recover $f$ and $g$. But of course the whole point of the cross ratio is that it's the same no matter how you slice it. Thanks for the example!

Comment: one question about this example:
the trick is that since the cross ratio stays invariant under "scanning by lines" and thus it's invariant under trafos of coordinates, we can fully reconstruct $f$ and $g$ from their values on $U \times 0$ independently of the choice of local coordinates,this is the message, right? the only point that I still not understand is why $\dim Z=1$ implies that $f$ and $g$ are already algebraically dependent, if we assume that $X$ *is* an open subset of an algebraic variety?

Comment: @TimGrosskreutz: If $X$ is algebraic, then $f$ and $g$ must be algebraic over $\mathbb{C}(z)$.

Comment: ...you mean it in the sense, that if $X$ is algebraic, then it's closed subset $Z$ is also algebraic, and $f$ and $g$ are algebraic over $K(Z)=\mathbb{C}(z)$, right?

Comment: @TimGrosskreutz: yes.

Answer (score 16):

The main question of the PI has been beautifully answered by Moret-Bailly, but not the
secondary question arisen from his expectation: "I would expect that it should be possible to write down a power series in two variables f(x,y) so that ℂ[[x,y]]/f(x,y) is non-algebraic."
though we got quite close in comments.

So for the record: this is not possible. Indeed, such a singularity would be analytic by a result of Michael Artin ( "On the solutions of analytic equations", Invent. Math. 5 1968, 277–291, cf. Angelo's answer to [Analytic vs. formal vs. étale singularities](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51530/analytic-vs-formal-vs-etale-singularities)) and then algebraic by Ulrich's comment (that is by Corollary 7.7.3 of the book by Casas-Alvero "Singularities of plane curves", London Mathematical Society Lecture Note Series, 278).

This is of course consistent with the fact that the example quoted by Moret-Bailly is in 
three variables.

Answer (score 10):

This is not answer, but a complement to the  comments above about isolated singularities of hypersurfaces.

Every isolated hypersurface singularity,  $R=\mathbb C[[x_1,
\ldots, x_n]]/f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$,  is not just algebraic
but also $k$-determined, for some $k \in \mathbb N$.

If $\mathfrak m \subset \mathbb C[[x_1,\ldots, x_n]]$ then we say that $f$ is $k$-determined
if for every $g\in \mathbb C[[x_1,
\ldots, x_n]]$ satisfying $f-g \in \mathfrak m^k$ there exists an automorphism $\varphi :\mathbb C[[x_1,\ldots, x_n]] \to \mathbb C[[x_1,
\ldots, x_n]]$ such that $\varphi(g)= f$.

Moreover, always assuming we have isolated singularities,  the natural number $k$ can be easily determined from $f$. For instance, in this [book](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=isBMwXgzKs4C&pg=PA312&lpg=PA312&dq=singularities+finite+determinacy&source=bl&ots=BY1PwMvRy7&sig=pFjYOodFXt_Hi2jKr77MnyZIAx0&hl=pt-BR&ei=2jx9Tq73LMm4tgfWyuxh&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CFMQ6AEwBQ#v=snippet&q=finite%2520determinacy&f=false)  you will find the following result:

If $\mathfrak m^{k+1} \subset
 \mathfrak m^2 J(f)$, where $J(f)$ is
 the Jacobian ideal of $f$, then $f$ is
 $k$-determined.